# Validating username and password with xml file in C# with WPF and XmlNode

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to validate username and password with saved credentials from an Xml File. But I only get Errors. It is my first Project in C# and WPF.Seems i don't get my variables into the XmlNode reader Block. How can I get the needed Variables into the Node Reader Block or where is the error in my resolution attempt?

```
namespace RAS_ERP
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            string UName = TxtUsername.Text;
            string PWord = TxtPassword.Text;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("/Resources/config.xml");
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("cfg", "urn:config-schema");
        XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes(
        "descendant::cfg:users[cfg:username = string 'UName']", nsmgr
            );
        foreach (XmlNode users in nodeList)
        { string username;
            string password;
            if (PWord == password && UName == username)
                    {
                NavigationService service = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
                service.Navigate(new Uri("MainMenu.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            } 
                } 
            else
            {
                LblError.string = "Username or Password Incorrect !";
            }
        }
    }



    private void Username_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

And the XML with which i want to validate the Login Credentials:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config xmlns="urn:config-schema">
<login>
<users>
  <username>
    admin
  </username>
  <password>
    admin
  </password>
  <firstname>
    Asim
  </firstname>
  <lastname>
    Shah
  </lastname>
  <permissions>
    2707
  </permissions>
</users>
</login>
</config>
```

Error List from VS 2017:

Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "MainMenue" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).  RAS-ERP C:\Users\ilove\source\repos\RAS-ERP\RAS-ERP\MainWindow.xaml.cs  49  Aktiv

Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "MainMenue" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).  RAS-ERP C:\Users\ilove\source\repos\RAS-ERP\RAS-ERP\MainWindow.xaml.cs  49  Aktiv

Fehler  CS1061  "Label" enthält keine Definition für "Text", und es wurde keine verfügbare Text-Erweiterungsmethode gefunden, die ein erstes Argument vom Typ "Label" akzeptiert (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).  RAS-ERP C:\Users\ilove\source\repos\RAS-ERP\RAS-ERP\MainWindow.xaml.cs  58  Aktiv

Fehler  CS0165  Verwendung der nicht zugewiesenen lokalen Variablen "username". RAS-ERP C:\Users\ilove\source\repos\RAS-ERP\RAS-ERP\MainWindow.xaml.cs  51  Aktiv

Fehler  CS0165  Verwendung der nicht zugewiesenen lokalen Variablen "password". RAS-ERP C:\Users\ilove\source\repos\RAS-ERP\RAS-ERP\MainWindow.xaml.cs  51  Aktiv

Fehler  CS1513  } erwartet. RAS-ERP C:\Users\ilove\source\repos\RAS-ERP\RAS-ERP\MainWindow.xaml.cs  69  Aktiv

Edit as the MainMenu problem got solved with changing to:

```
        foreach (XmlNode users in nodeList)
        { string username;
            string password;
            if (PWord == password && UName == username)
                    {
                NavigationService service = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
                service.Navigate(new Uri("MainMenu.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
```

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Show the exact errors you are getting as text via an [edit].

Comment: Is that your actual xml? The namespace is declared incorrectly, it is missing an "n" - xml***n***s

Comment: It is the actual. I added the n now but no change in result on the errors

Comment: Did you misspell `MainMenue`? Maybe it should be `MainMenu`? The problem has nothing to do with the xml.

Comment: the second page is called mainmenue.xaml so it is correct.

Comment: On string username and string password it is alreadz submitting error that the variable is not defined but should be defined by the result from the XML file.

Comment: Do you have a `using <namespace>` declaration for that Type? You have a reference problem, not a problem with your xml logic.

Comment: using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XmlConfiguration;

Comment: I'm assuming the `MainMenue` type is not in any of the `System` namespaces so you will need to add a `using` for whatever namespace it is in.

Comment: MainMenu Problem solved with changing the code to:             foreach (XmlNode users in nodeList)
            { string username;
                string password;
                if (PWord == password && UName == username)
                        {
                    NavigationService service = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
                    service.Navigate(new Uri("MainMenu.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                }

Comment: But still I get errors about the undefined variables as they doesn't get defined from the XML File. Seems it is not parsing.

Comment: I also changed the name of the file to MainMenu.xaml as it is more proper english

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution by using XDocument Loader and Xelement.
Needed to convert the variable with the result from the xml into string by using .ToString method but i got the result i needed:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XmlConfiguration;




namespace RAS_ERP
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var UName = TxtUsername.Text;
        var PWord = TxtPassword.Text;
        XDocument config = XDocument.Load("../Resources/config.xml");
        var query = from o in config.Root.Elements("user")
                    where (string)o.Element("username") == UName
                    select (string)o.Element("username").Value;
        var query2 = from o in config.Root.Elements("user")
                     where (string)o.Element("username") == UName
                     select o.Element("password").Value;
        var password = query2.ToString();
            if ( PWord == password )
            {
                NavigationService service = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
                service.Navigate(new Uri("MainMenu.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
            else
            {
                LblError.Content = "Username or Password Incorrect !";
            }
        }

    private void Username_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}


}
```